# Resizing texture/RT

Tags: c++, c, directx

I am trying to double buffer some frames in my applications. However, double buffering requires me to change Texture2D size based on the region which I am trying to keep an extra block of data of.

1. Is it better to request a new CreateTexture2D for each region for double buffer?

   - Would resizing the Texture2D be effective solution based on the change of region size? Doesn't resizing require you to **recreate** the Texture2D resources/request a new RT.
2. Or is it better to create a Texture2D that is the full scene of the application and only use portions that are required?

   - Would that take up too much memory?
   - Is it possible to adjust the Shader to apply the effects on **only on a region** of the Texture2D.

Say the context of the application is a 3D game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean double buffering in the context of the primary window render target, you should be using a [Swap Chain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which has N-buffering support built in (e.g. set `BufferCount` to 2).  When the window size changes, call `ResizeBuffers`.

Comment: That is the BackBuffer.I am talking with double buffering with Texture2D.

Comment: @mk1 The `IDXGISwapChain` (see link above) encapsulates the back buffer.  You should be creating a swap chain, getting the automatically created back buffer (`GetBackBuffer()`), and creating a render target view on it.